# Does anyone know of an open source operations management system?

Tags: java, php, python, c

Hi I dont know if this is the right place to ask... but could someone tell me if there is any open source operations management system available?
My apologies if someone thinks that this is not the right place to ask this...I came across openOMS but looks like that project is dead..
Thanks!

Comment: in java? php? python? c? did you forget perl\flash\couldfusion\ruby?

Comment: what do you mean by _operation management system_?  If you mean _IT operations_, perhaps the fellows from [http://serverfault.com/](http://serverfault.com/) can help you better.

Comment: @Dagon do you know any OMS written in any language.. if yes let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by operations, you mean "automated deployment and maintenance of systems", perhaps you're looking for something like [Opscode and their Chef framework.](http://www.opscode.com/) I just happen to have heard of this one, probably there are many others.